# hiding the vue routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, privacy

I have my vue routes as

```
const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
    next()
    return
  }
  next('/login')
}

const checkAgentPermissions = () => {
  return false
}

export const routes = [
 {
  path: '/users',
    beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
    component: Layout,
    meta: { title: 'Agent Onboarding', icon: 'address-card' },
    hidden: checkAgentPermissions,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Users',
        component: () => import('@/views/users/index.vue')
      },
      {
        .....some more childrens
      }
    ]
 }
]
```

but hidden is always true, when called through functions.
and if i change the option hidden from checkAgentPermissions to false

```
 hidden: false // works perfectly
```

why function doesn't return false, actually i need to do some check in fn and then return true/false depending on that.

forEach route i am rendering them in vue component by checking if hidden is true/false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to execute your hidden function:

```
hidden: checkAgentPermissions(),
children: [
...
```

Comment: it worked, but can you tell me why ifAuthenticated doesn't needed those brackets?

Comment: Because `beforeEnter` is a hook method, `ifAuthenticated` will be executed when it triggers.